# Access violation in factory method

Tags: c++, visual-studio, oop, pointers, factory

[EDIT] error was somewhere else as @litelite helped me find out, no need for more answers

I have factory method called `MakeDevice` in my factory class which returns a pointer to a base class object (but actually points to an object of one of the child classes, depending on a condition).

When executing the program, I get a xC0000005: Access violation error. The line that the Visual Studio debugger stops at is the following:

```
ret = new DeviceA;
```

Code:
The base class is BaseDevice, and the two child classes are DeviceA and DeviceB. DeviceModel is an enum type to make it easier.

```
BaseDevice *DeviceFactory::MakeDevice(DeviceModel model) {
    BaseClass *ret;
    switch(model) {
        case model_deviceA:
            ret = new DeviceA;    // debugger stops here
            break;
        case model_deviceB:
            ret = new DeviceB;
            break;
        default:
            printf("error");
            break;
        }
    return ret;
}
```

Has anyone experienced something similar?  I've read that this was the correct way of implementing this sort of factory. Im also open to design changes, as long as I can abstractly use the methods on a baseclass in the same fashion.

Comment: What's inside the `DeviceA` constructor?

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: If there is an error, your function returns an uninitialised pointer.

Comment: for the moment I never get to the default case so I just wrote a print whatever  in my question. thanks to @litelite, I noticed DeviceA's constructor contains a function pointer call to a DLL function, I'll check if that could be it

Comment: So after all it was a LoadLibrary call that did not return a dll handle for some reason I'll investigate, thanks again for your participation

Answer (score 1):

You should also initialize ret with nullptr.